# Capturing area of the screen without a Desktop Environment?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, dwm, screenshot

I'm running OpenSuse with dwm as a window manager. Since I made the switch from KDE, I haven't found a way to take a screenshot or even capture part of my screen.

Is there a way I can do this in a command-line environment?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/125524/linux-cli-screenshot-without-x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The euphoniously named [scrot](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/scrot) takes screenshots from the command line...

It has a couple of simple options, including a time delay and image quality.

If you are wanting to take a shot in the console, and you are running a framebuffer, then you can use [fbgrab](http://hem.bredband.net/gmogmo/fbgrab/).

Comment: I had problems with fbgrab. I can attest that my frame buffer is 1366x768 but both fbgrab and fbshot think /dev/fb0 is 1024x768, which scales the console fonts and makes me sad. When I give fbgrab the width and height it says there is not enough data.

Comment: @BentFX are you *sure* that the actual framebuffer resolution is `1366x768`, or is it just your screen (panel) native resolution? What does `cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/{modes,virtual_size}` give? Also, if you do a 1024x768 dump, is the image cropped?

Comment: Ok, I can attest to the fact that I'm often caught speaking out of my class. Yes it is 1024x768, but my X screen is 1366 and that's part of what made the fbgrab output look so bad. 1366 is the native width and it is sharp. 1024x768 is fuzzy. From the console it looks nicely antialiased, but a picture of it is just ugly. :) I stand corrected!

Answer (score 11):

ImageMagick comes with the `import` utility to take screenshots. It has tons of options, but by default it lets you draw a rectangle on the screen and saves just that portion. If you want an entire window you can use `-window ID`; the identifier "root" captures the entire screen

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) under Xmonad without any desktop environment and it has been working well. Shutter is a GUI app with a decent amount of features.

Most of the time I would type "`shutter -s`" in a launcher/terminal and the program will let me choose the area of the screen that I want to capture. Then I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the file will be saved to my home folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for minimalistic solutions, your `Xorg` server might already comes with a tool called **`xwd`**. If not, and you'd install it separately, it might be the lightest possibility - the binary is just 27 KB in size. Watch out, because it outputs data on `stdout`!

But **the problem** with `xwd` is that it dumps the screenshot in an *[XWD X Window Dump image data](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=XWD)* format, not a standard image. You can view such *dumps* with a companion **`xwud`** program (run `xwud -in yourdumpfile`). To get a typical image file, you'd need to convert it using something like `xwdtopnm` or `convert` (from `ImageMagick`).