# Xmonad how to take screenshots

Tags: gnome, xmonad, screenshot

I get  the following error when I run `gnome-screenshot`

```
** Message: 11:08:24.901: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
```

Also tried `PrtScrn`, `Ctrl+PrtScrn` and `Ctrl+Alt+PrtScrn` to copy screenshots to clipboard but nothing is pasted `gnome-paint`.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25073/117549

Comment: `shutter` worked but only for screen selection; probably need desktop environment